# Find the matching React Node for a given HTML Node

Tags: reactjs

For the following example:

```js
const Home = () => <div id="demo">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

Is there any code that would allow me to get the JSX element and its props similar to the ReactDevTools Chrome Extension?

```js
const div = getElementById("demo");
// ??
```

[image: React Dev Tools]

Comment: sorry if my question is stupid. But what would be the use-case for such thing? I assume useRef isn't enough for your use-case right?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to change the source of the component itself - I want to write a small helper which allows to jump right into the code of any component with `alt + click`

Comment: you can try examining `react-devtools-*` source code on the [official react packages](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/main/packages).

Comment: Using that would break react-dev-tools as only one instance is allowed:
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/51947a14bb24bd151f76f6fc0acdbbc404de13f7/packages/react-devtools-shared/src/hook.js#L22-L24

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking to access the `h1` component in your example and for instance setting a value for it, what I would usually do is  this:
 `const h1 = document.getElementById("demo").getElementByTagName('h1)`
and then you can use `innerHtml` to set the value ( or set it with the dangerously variant ). the h1 doesn't need to be a direct child. Some other functions that would come handy instead of `getElementByTagName` to select the elements based on their classes or idis or tags and ... are  :

```
querySelector()
querySelectors()
getElementsByClassname()
```

anyway, not quite sure if this was what you were asking for!

Comment: No - I know how to get the html element - I am looking for a way to get the JSX Element instance from it

Answer (score 0):

Either of the following will work with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> to show the props of each component.

#### Using [HOC](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-gwen-7qbh4?file=/src/App.js)

You can create a Higher-Order component to get the props viewed. You can export existing components you want this functionality wrapped with `withViewProps`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const withViewProps = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return (props) => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    return (
      <div
        onClick={(e) => {
          setShow(e.altKey);
        }}
      >
        <>
          {show && (
            <>
              {WrappedComponent.name}
              {JSON.stringify(Object.entries(props))}
              <button onClick={() => setShow(false)}>x</button>
            </>
          )}
        </>
        <WrappedComponent {...props} />
      </div>
    );
  };
};

const Home = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.text}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

const WrappedHome = withViewProps(Home);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <WrappedHome
        text={"Hello World"}
        value={20}
        myF={() => {
          alert("Yes!");
        }}
      />
      <WrappedHome
        text={"Hello World"}
        value={20}
        myF={() => {
          alert("Yes!");
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[Code Sandbox: HOC](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-gwen-7qbh4?file=/src/App.js)

#### Using [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)

You can create root level component to wrap all the nested components. Then you can iterate over all the nested children to add the functionality to view the props. This way you do not need to export each of your react components.

```
import React, { useState, Children, isValidElement } from "react";

const ViewPropsAll = ({ children }) => {
  const renderChild = (children) => {
    return Children.map(children, (child) => {
      if (isValidElement(child)) {
        return (
          <ViewProps data={child.props}>
            <child.type
              {...child.props}
              children={renderChild(child.props.children)}
            />
          </ViewProps>
        );
      }
      return child;
    });
  };

  return <>{renderChild(children)}</>;
};

const ViewProps = (props) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div
      onClick={(e) => {
        setShow(e.altKey);
      }}
    >
      <>
        {show && (
          <>
            {JSON.stringify(Object.entries(props.data))}
            <button onClick={() => setShow(false)}>x</button>
          </>
        )}
      </>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

const Home = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.text}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ViewPropsAll>
      <Home
        text={"Hello World"}
        value={20}
        myF={() => {
          alert("Yes!");
        }}
      />
      <Home
        text={"Hello Hello"}
        value={30}
        myF={() => {
          alert("Noo!");
        }}
      />
    </ViewPropsAll>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[Code Sandbox: Render Props](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-hooks-trxcu?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @jantimon, check this out !!

Comment: Hey @amila - thanks realy cool POC! :) I am looking for a way which doesn't need to change the App code itself and also doesn't inject additional HTML elements - similar to the react-dev-tools

Comment: Okay, but you can change the logic to show a tooltip instead of adding HTML if you want. Isn't it functionality you add to your code? Or is it actually an alternative chrome extension for rect-dev-tools you develop?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use getElementById https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

But React has a built in hook that let you access child references. Check the `useRef` doc https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

**Example**

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const Home = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  console.log(ref)
 
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

useRef will only returns states and props if you pass the ref to a React component. In your case it will returns the HTML element